# How to prevent same user login from multiple times at the same time in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on web application in MVC4-asp.net.For login I am using Simple membership Provider method to login.All is working properly but according to project requirement there will be no same user can not login at the same time on different machine.how to make changes in MVC simple membership.if any user is logged in and any one try to login at the same time  using same username then it will be display message like "This user is already Logged In" and user will be not able to log in at that time.

Please give some suggestion on that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try searching? This has been discussed plenty of times already. You don't want to do this, because logged in users can lose (access to) their cookies, causing them to be unable to log in anymore, from anywhere. Alternatively, you could implement a "heartbeat" saying "I'm still logged in!", which also has many potential problems. Instead, go for the simplest approach, let each new login for a given user invalidate all earlier sessions for said user.

Comment: A signal-r solution should work for you , have you checked it already ?

Comment: @MDDDC SignalR is one of many ways to implement a "heartbeat" to determine whether someone is logged in, but it's really a small part of the overall implementation.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok , I understand what you mean, I will provide a full working example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do it by many ways, simple approach is

1. Set one flag at the time of login into database.
2. Check flag every time when you are sign in.
3. Remove flag at time of logout.

There are some issues in using this approach like what if user is close browser without logged out, for that you can set session time out.Hope this will help.